# How can I make a background image of a site start off fitting to screen and then zoomable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a really big image 4096 x 4096. I want to make it my background image for a site and when the site loads I'd like the full image displayed on any screen size, but I also want it to be zoomable.

Right now I've just made the image have height and width 100% in my CSS but obviously that keeps it at 100% no matter what. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by full size ? 100% of the screen or 100% of it's original size? And what do you mean by zoomable ? Like with two fingers on a mobile?

Comment: 100% of the screen, sorry for not being clear. And yeah thats what I mean by zoomable. I guess magnifying would be a better word. Essentially I'd like the ability to press command + and have the image get bigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is using something like [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) to allow you zoom in to an image.

This link [here](http://build-failed.blogspot.ca/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html) explains the process of breaking up the image into the required tiles.

Does that help?

Comment: This helps so much! It's exactly what I was thinking, how did you read my mind?

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need a property `background-size: cover`in background like below:

```
body {
    background: url(xxx) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question well, then, simply doing the following may be what you want :

```
body {
    background: url(path-to/4096x4096.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

See the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/az8o8ryo/1/).

Comment: yeah I tried something like this and it doesn't work, maybe my question isn't really clear. It's kind of hard to articulate. I guess the best way to describe it is that I would like it to be almost like google maps, where the initial image is of the world, and then you have the ability to zoom in and see more detail.  Thanks for the answer though.